# Push to .git but denied to wrong user , finally solved

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-push

I googling a lot. but it still report an error after execute 'git push -u origin master'.
Finally I execute 'git push -u origin master' success, but I really don't know where the error is. Please read on patiently the content as follow.

1, I've had a git account 'HelenZeng', now I have another account 'Snowbabe'

2, I generate two ssh key, one is id_rsa_helen, another is id_rsa_snow

3, I touch ~/.ssh/config

```
#github.snowbabe
  Host github.com-Snowbabe
          HostName github.com
          User Snowbabe
          IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_snow

  #github.helenzeng
  Host github.com-HelenZeng
          HostName github.com
          User HelenZeng
          IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_helen
```

4, I have tried googling, to be honest, I really don't know why use ssh-add

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_helen
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_snow
$ ssh-add -l
  4096 SHA256:Ky5cNi8JKMUuguV0Snt4epmwFn2MgAk19nzF3MJujWU 
  /Users/'username'/.ssh/id_rsa_helen (RSA)
  4096 SHA256:hMfQyemWSz+f+AHrmsbZdhrDb11U+wA4xXeG3X1u28E 
  /Users/'username'/.ssh/id_rsa_snow (RSA)
```

5, I created a react app project, and I want to push it to gitHub repository( to git account 'Snowbabe').

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:Snowbabe/React-study.git
```

6, Here is my .git/config

```
[remote "origin"]
       url = git@github.com:Snowbabe/React-study.git
       fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

it's correct url

7, Finally step

```
$ git push -u origin master
  ERROR: Permission to Snowbabe/React-study.git denied to HelenZeng.
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Try to Solve:

```
$ ssh-add -l
 4096 SHA256:Ky5cNi8JKMUuguV0Snt4epmwFn2MgAk19nzF3MJujWU 
 /Users/'username'/.ssh/id_rsa_helen (RSA)
 4096 SHA256:hMfQyemWSz+f+AHrmsbZdhrDb11U+wA4xXeG3X1u28E 
 /Users/'username'/.ssh/id_rsa_snow (RSA)

/** delete all **/
$ ssh-add -D
 All identities removed.

/** just ssh-add id_rsa_snow **/
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_snow
$ ssh-add -l
 4096 SHA256:hMfQyemWSz+f+AHrmsbZdhrDb11U+wA4xXeG3X1u28E 
 /Users/yaxian/.ssh/id_rsa_snow (RSA)
```

Now, execute 'git push -u origin master'

```
$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 18, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 165.52 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:Snowbabe/React-study.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Successfully.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: This would be better if you posted it as answer to a well formed question. What was the problem you faced? What did you try? And then post your solution in the answer.

Comment: Please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) about self-answering. It's allowed and encouraged, but it still needs to follow the Q&A format.

Comment: @HelenZe FYI, just improved my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to know what `ssh-add` does, and why the first way to use `ssh-add` failed while the second way succeeded. I'm answering with that assumption in mind.

**Why `ssh-add` works as it does**

`ssh-add` is used to load specific identities in your ssh agent. You have several identities available to you, and your ssh agent will offer them to any server you try to connect to, in an order I don't fully understand.

Under typical circumstances, a given server would only accept one of your identities. For example, let's say I added `id_rsa_server1` to connect to host1, and `id_rsa_server2` to connect to host2. When I connect to host1, ssh offers `id_rsa_server1` to the server and connects successfully. When I connect to host2, ssh first offers `id_rsa_server1`, which fails, then tries the next one, `is_rsa_server2`, which now succeeds.

Your problem when you loaded the two identities is that `github.com` knows both helen and snow. You want to log in with snow, since that's the account that has permissions on that particular repo, but the ssh layer succeeds with the first accepted key, helen, which doesn't have the required permissions.

So when you unload your identities and load only the right one, things work because this times you log in to `github.com` as snow, with the required permissions to do the push.

I hope this helps clarify what is going on.

**Alternative and recommended solution with `.ssh/config`**

Because you're connecting to `github.com` by that name, I think your `.ssh/config` does not do anything. It would only do something if you connected to `github.com-Snowbabe` as the server name.

This should work:

`.ssh/config` with User=`git`:

```
Host github.com-Snowbabe
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_snow
```

set your Git repo to use this remote name:

```
git remote set-url origin github.com-Snowbabe/React-study.git
```

With these settings, your ssh agent will use the right identity file when using that host name: the alias defined in `.ssh/config` specifies the user name (must always be `git` on `github.com`) and identity (Snow's RSA key). You still need to `ssh-add id_rsa_snow` as before, but this configuration overrides what identity is offered first upon connecting via ssh.

Edit: I've now tested this procedure well, in the context of answering a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55665572/git-tries-to-use-global-user-when-i-try-to-push-with-ssh/55677031#55677031), and corrected some mistakes above in the process.

Comment: It's the best perfect answer for me. I really want to vote for you, but this new account with less than 15 reputation can not vote for anybody. Thank you very much. Forgive my poor english.

Comment: I will test the procedure this afternoon in Beijing time, and really thank you again.

Comment: Glad I could help. Let me know if the alternative solution works, then I'll update the answer with any feedback you provide.

Comment: I really don't know why this isn't working. I have to delete all identities and add the wanted identity everytime.

Comment: First, sorry for late reply.

I test it that you said, change .ssh/config with User=git, React-study.git pull works under ssh-add id_rsa_snow circumstances. I really know that I lack of git information， I would read git's help document carefully. 

Thank you very much.